# I have got error like FileNotFoundError while solving the Object detection part but I have these file I my directory even It is giving an error ..why?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, object-detection

While solving the object detection part I have got the error.

```
 for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
  image = Image.open(image_path)
  # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
  # result image with boxes and labels on it.
  image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
  # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
  image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
  # Actual detection.
  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)
  plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
  plt.imshow(image_np)
```

Got the error like

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
----> 2   image = Image.open(image_path)
3   # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
4   # result image with boxes and labels on it.
5   image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)

c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tfold\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
2876
2877     if filename:
-> 2878         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
2879         exclusive_fp = True
2880

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Microsoft/Desktop/My Folder/models-1.13.0/research/test_images/image1.jpg'

But I have kept the file in that test_images folder I want to even I have kept images inside that particular folder why I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if it will solve your problem, but I can suggest you to use:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Instead of using:

```
import Image
```

If you haven’t done it already.